# How do I upload using AWS S3 PRESIGNED URL as HTML?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Currently, S3 PRESIGNED URL is being obtained through SPRING BOOT.

I want to upload an image from FRONT by passing the URL in HTML.

However, the CODE you have written now receives SignatureDoesNotMatch.

MY SERVER CODE

```
public String getSignedURL(String fileName){
    ZonedDateTime uploadTime=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul"));

    Date expiration=new Date();
    long expTimeMillis =expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis+=1000*60*1; //1Min
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

    //+uploadTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy.mm.dd HH:mm:ss z"))

    String objectKey="boardimages/"+fileName;
    URL urls=null;
    try {
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest url = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .withExpiration(expiration);

        url.addRequestParameter(Headers.S3_CANNED_ACL, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead.toString());
        urls = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(url);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("pre-signed url : "+urls);
    return urls.toString();
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(Model model,HttpServletRequest request){
    Map<String,String[]> emp=request.getParameterMap();

    String fileName=emp.get("file")[0];
    System.out.println("uploading file Name = "+fileName);

    String persgined=awsService.getSignedURL(fileName);
    model.addAttribute("fileName","boardimages/"+fileName); //object key -> .jpg   boardimage->s3 bucket dir
    model.addAttribute("url",persgined);
    model.addAttribute("accesskey",awsService.getAccessKey());
    return "galleryUrlUpload";
}
```

my html form code

```
<form role="form" action="#" th:action="${url}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>-->
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${fileName}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="${accesskey}" />
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="click"></input>
```

My Error

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>---</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20210310T081246Z 20210310/ap-northeast-2/s3/aws4_request 38d7447c7cb20368bb9a690afc14029b6983a423b7400f214d4acb119ab181b6
</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>
fe2cb0da2a770b64014d971c270731d70788519447f64f63dfc9cd881d0c23c1
</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>
41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 31 30 33 31 30 54 30 38 31 32 34 36 5a 0a 32 30 32 31 30 33 31 30 2f 61 70 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 33 38 64 37 34 34 37 63 37 63 62 32 30 33 36 38 62 62 39 61 36 39 30 61 66 63 31 34 30 32 39 62 36 39 38 33 61 34 32 33 62 37 34 30 30 66 32 31 34 64 34 61 63 62 31 31 39 61 62 31 38 31 62 36
</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>
POST /boardimages/1540.jpg X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAV4JZWYET2PT6UO6G%2F20210310%2Fap-northeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210310T081246Z&X-Amz-Expires=59&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-amz-acl=public-read host:infostarbinary.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>
50 4f 53 54 0a 2f 62 6f 61 72 64 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 31 35 34 30 2e 6a 70 67 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 56 34 4a 5a 57 59 45 54 32 50 54 36 55 4f 36 47 25 32 46 32 30 32 31 30 33 31 30 25 32 46 61 70 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 32 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 31 30 33 31 30 54 30 38 31 32 34 36 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 35 39 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 26 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3d 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 69 6e 66 6f 73 74 61 72 62 69 6e 61 72 79 2e 73 33 2e 61 70 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44
</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>RG1VPG1549WMPKZ9</RequestId>
<HostId>
XMnFDE1xzfvkwsLsJPVuxUEbLRlH5muADarR/p5KCTp3U9N0f6uI1CR8WL+rWTPbI0V4kZ7LpzA=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I referenced here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.11.4/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html but didn't understand the policy and signature of the last html.

What do I need to pass as policy and signature in order to work?
Or please tell me to upload s3 via presigned url using html.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java to perform this use case, please refer to the Java documentation as opposed to Python. See:

[Working with Amazon S3 Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html)

The logic to upload content via a presigned URL using the AWS SDK for Java V2 can be found in that topic.

If you are not familiar with using Java V2, please refer to this [quick start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html).

**UPDATE:**
If you want to upload content from a web page (as your comment suggests), then you should use the AWS SDK for Javascript - not the Java API. Here is the example to refer to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-create-presigendurl-put

Comment: I looked at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_kr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html page and implemented that feature.
However, the uploaded example and the example in the link above are the way to upload files from the java server.
I want to upload an image and I want to upload it from the front, not the server.
I tried the example page you uploaded, but the same error appears...